# Permission to add rows to a protected sheet

Tags: google-sheets

One of my sheets has 1 protected column, a user with no permission to that column cannot add another row to the sheet. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

Instead of protecting the whole column `B1:B`, protect a range in column `B`. Say `B1:A11`.

[image]